# Homework Help Regarding Calculation of PI

Tags: java

I'm a new member, and I have been having trouble with my Java homework. Basically, I have to create a program to calculate the value of pi by simulating throwing darts at a dart board, and I've been modifying my code, trying different ways, and looking up information online, yet to no avail. I would like some help regarding my code below. Is there anything I am doing wrong and is there any code I can improve on?

*Here are the important directions for the assignment I have to complete:*

- Use top/down design and procedural abstraction in this program.  In other words, put functional units into methods.
- Prompt the user for how many times darts should be thrown in a trial as well as the number of trials.
- Estimate pi for each trial.
- Choose random values of x and y.
- Count any (x, y) coordinate that satisfies x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1 as a hit within the circle as a hit, and any coordinates outside the circle as a miss.
- Calculate the average of the estimates for all trials and print the results.

Also note: I am not familiar with OOP just yet; however, that is my next module's topic. Please refrain from any advanced topics I am not familiar with. :)

**Edit:** I have modified my code after some very helpful advice. It seems that my program is running correctly now. Is there anything I could improve on?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Darts
{
    public static int prompt(int numDarts)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("%60s%n", "How many darts would you like to throw per trial? ");
        System.out.print("                                 ");
        numDarts = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        return numDarts;
    }

    public static int prompt2(int numTrials)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("%51s%n", "How many trials would you like? ");
        System.out.print("                                  ");
        numTrials = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        return numTrials;
    }

    public static double[] calculations(int numTrials, int numDarts, double zTotal, double totalCounter)
    {
        Random num = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < numTrials; i++)
        {
            int wins = 0;
            for(int l = 0; l < numDarts; l++)
            {
                double xCoordinate = num.nextDouble();
                double yCoordinate = num.nextDouble();
                zTotal = Math.pow(xCoordinate, 2) + Math.pow(yCoordinate, 2);
                if(zTotal <= 1)
                {
                    wins++;
                }
            }
            zTotal = 4 * ((double)wins / numDarts);
            totalCounter += zTotal;
            System.out.printf("%30s" + "%2d" + "%8s" + "%1.6f%n", "Trial [", i + 1, "]: pi = ", zTotal);
        }
        double[] extract = new double[2];
        extract[0] = zTotal;
        extract[1] = totalCounter;
        return extract;
        }

    public static void printResults(int numTrials, double totalCounter)
    {
        System.out.println("Estimate of PI: " + (totalCounter / numTrials));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double z = 0;
        int darts = 0,
            trials = 0;
        double totalCount = 0.0;

        darts += prompt(darts);
        trials += prompt2(trials);
        double[] twoValues = calculations(trials, darts, z, totalCount);
        z = twoValues[0];
        totalCount = twoValues[1];
        printResults(trials, totalCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting assignment. What is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: what's going on with this line ?  --- > `zTotal = Math.pow(xCoordinate, 2) + Math.pow(yCoordinate, 2);`   ... I'm not really seeing what's this calculation going to do, and how you figure out what is a "successful dart throw"

Comment: Remind me also -  what is `PI` ? is that acronym?  Or geometric PI like 3.1415.........

Comment: Can you link to something about that

Comment: @Coffee From *"calculate the value of pi"* I would assume 3.1416....

Comment: I think you can tackle this in a few ways. PI being C / D is one way

Comment: I think you want to be using floating point for `(wins / numDarts)`.

Comment: Yes, it is the mathematical abstraction of PI, sorry for the confusion. I need help regarding the output I am getting. With the code above, my output comes out to have values of 0.00. I am supposed to get close approximations of the numerical value of PI and an estimated value of PI. 

@Coffee `zTotal = Math.pow(xCoordinate, 2) + Math.pow(yCoordinate, 2);` is the equivalent of z = x^2 + y^2 and is assigned to the argument zTotal.  The next line states that if the value of zTotal is less than or equal to 1, then the "wins" argument will increment by one.

Comment: @Tetramental - Ok , I'm starting to get it better. When I run with the arguments of `1, 1` I always get `4` as output , that's interesting.  I think paper & pencil can help a bit -  just walk through a sample input and make sure it makes sense

Comment: Just to give you a hint as to the class of problem you're solving:  these are [Monte Carlo trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) you're performing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the big picture, I think the biggest issue you need to work on is variable scope. It does not make sense to pass in to `calculations` variables like `wins`, `xCoordinate`, and `yCoordinate`. These should be local variables declared within the body of `calculations`.

Also, it seems you are mixing data from all trials together instead of recording the results of a given trial individually.

It might also be good to write one method that just runs one trial instead of your current method that runs all trials and contains all the logic for a given trial within it. You are also reusing `i` for both the inner and outer loop. That will cause undesired results.

Here is an example of how you might run one single trial within a separate method:

```
public static int runTrial(int numDarts){
    int wins = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < numDarts; i++)
    {
        double xCoordinate = random.nextDouble();
        double yCoordinate = random.nextDouble();
        double zTotal = Math.pow(xCoordinate, 2) + Math.pow(yCoordinate, 2);
        if(zTotal <= 1)
        {
            wins++;
        }
    }
    return wins;
}
```

Below is also an example of how you could separate the results of the trials.

```
public static void runAllTrials(int numTrials, int numDarts)
{
    int totalCounter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numTrials; i++)
    {
        int wins = runTrial(numDarts);
        System.out.println(
                String.format("Trial [%d]: Pi = %g ",
                        (i+1),
                        calculatePi(wins, numDarts)
                )
        );

        totalCounter += wins;

    }
    System.out.println(
            String.format("Overall: Pi = %g ",
                calculatePi(totalCounter, numDarts * numTrials)
        )
    );


}

public static double calculatePi(int wins, int darts){
    return 4*((double)wins) / darts;
}
```

The final output being:

```
How many darts would you like to throw per trial? 1000

How many trials would you like? 10

Trial [1]: Pi = 3.16400 
Trial [2]: Pi = 3.08800 
Trial [3]: Pi = 3.21200 
Trial [4]: Pi = 3.20000 
Trial [5]: Pi = 3.11200 
Trial [6]: Pi = 3.18000 
Trial [7]: Pi = 3.10000 
Trial [8]: Pi = 3.06000 
Trial [9]: Pi = 3.09200 
Trial [10]: Pi = 3.04400 
Overall: Pi = 3.12520
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Changing one of the "i" increments completely changed all my values to what I should be looking at. That and a bit of tinkering (reordering some code).